yarn link is causing issues
I maintain a library that's used by a project I'm working on. To develop a new feature in the library, I set up a symlink using yarn link, which connected the library's source to the project's node_modules.
However, when I tried to build the project, I encountered compile errors. When I used my IDE to trace the imports from the project to the library, I noticed that it was pointing to the src folder of the library instead of the dist folder. This misdirection led to the compilation issues.
Here’s my package.json configuration in the library:
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js",
    "./authentication": "./dist/authentication/index.js",
    ...
  }
}

And here’s my tsconfig.json:
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "declarationDir": "./dist/types",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../../node_modules/@types",
      "../../node_modules",
      "./dist/types"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"]
}

I've tried an alternative solution by replacing the version in the project's dependencies with the exact file path, but this approach caused me to accidentally push the path in one of my PRs. I want to avoid making this mistake again and ensure that juniors on the team don't run into the same issue.
Any help on how to correctly set up the yarn link so that the project properly references the compiled dist folder would save me a lot of time and effort. Thanks in advance!
And An important side note:
the library uses pnpm package manager, where project uses yarn.
pnpm version -- 9.0.5
yarn version -- 1.22.22
I have tried removing the node moduels in both library and project, and I tried running the yarn link and yarn build, but this caused the same error.
I tried using both
pnpm link ../library
and yarn link 
and yarn link <project_name>.
